# Сравнить n списков и получить список с наиболее повторяющимися в каждом индексе элементами

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

```
seg1_int = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
seg2_int = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] 
seg3_int = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

`seg1[0] , seg2[0], seg3[0] = [1,2,1]`

`seg_res[0] = 1`

даны несколько списков, от трех и более, цель - получить новый список, каждый элемент которого - наиболее повторяющийся элемент индексов трех списков. Не представляю как подступиться к этому вопросу, спасибо!

Comment: а если все элементы одинаковые, или найдется два самых частых, тогда что?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-most-frequent-element-in-a-list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, и вам нужно получить наиболее повторяющийся элемент индексов трех списков, то, возможно, вам подойдет такое решение:

```
import numpy as np
```

Исходные:

```
seg1_int = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
seg2_int = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] 
seg3_int = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Код:

```
def icomp(*args):
    lst = np.array([*args]).T
    return np.argmax(np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, 1, lst), axis=1)
```

Проверка:

```
print(icomp(seg1_int, seg2_int ,seg3_int))
print(icomp([1,1,1,1,1], [1,3,1,3,1], [3,1,3,1,3], [3,1,3,1,3], [3,1,3,1,3]))
```

Результат соответственно:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[3 1 3 1 3]
```

Comment: Ход решения понятен, немного уточню, seg1[0] , seg2[0], seg3[0] = [1,2,1] - результат сравнения этих индексов seg_result[0]=[1], т.к. из 3х значений здесь две единицы. Нужно чтобы функция проходилась по всем индексам и в пределах каждого индекса seg_n[n] seg_2n[n] итп сравнивала кол-во встреченных повторяющихся чисел и в новый список выводила максимально встречающийся элемент. Например seg1[10] , seg2[10], seg3[10],seg4[10], seg5[10] = [2,3,5,2,10] 
seg_res[10]= [2]

Comment: Именно это мой код и делает.

Comment: Тогда не очень понятно, почему в случае "print(icomp([1,1,1,1,1], [1,3,1,3,1], [3,1,3,1,3], [3,1,3,1,3], [3,1,3,1,3]))" выводится [3 1 3 1 3], а не [1 1 3 1 3].

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski наверное, потому, что , например, по нулевому индексу в списках троек 3 штуки, а единиц всего 2?

Comment: @strawdog подождите, нулевой элемент это список [1,1,1,1,1], там вообще троек нет.

Comment: нулевой элемент - это элемент с индексом "0" в прилагаемых списках. соответственно, нулевые элементы, стало быть - 1,1,3,3,3